# How to pass JSON string in the JSON body of an HTTP request?

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, servicenow

How can i pass a JSON string in the JSON body of the HTTP request? The request is sent by ServiceNow to Azure Devops to set the content of a pipeline variable.
The Json body is as below:

```
{
   "resources":{
      "repositories":{
         "self":{
            "refName":"refs/heads/master"
         }
      }
   },
   "variables":{
      "request":{
         "value":"{"key1": "value1"}"  #here, i declare the json string
      }
   }
}
```

`"{"key1": "value1"}"` is the json string that i want to pass (this is just a sample of the string).

I have tried backslash '' in front of the braces. `"\{"key1": "value1"\}"` It didn't work.

I have tried to put the braces between single or double quotations. "'{'"key1": "value1"'}'" It didn't work.

Do you have any idea? Maybe it is doable with the ServiceNow's language but i am not expert of it. As Azure Devops only accepts strings as pipeline variables, i have to send the json as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes of the value:

```
{\"key1\": \"value1\"}
```